# Function statement() that outputs the sum of the deposit and the sum of the withdraw

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with this question:

Write a function statement() that takes as input a list of floating point numbers, with positive numbers representing deposits to and negative numbers representing withdrawals from a bank account. Your function should return a list of two floating point number; the first will be the sum of the deposits and the second will be the sum of the withdrawals

code I have:
import math

```
def statement (bank):

deposit = []
withdrawal = []
i = 0
    for i in range(1, len(bank)):

        if bank[i] >= 0:
            deposit.append(bank[i])

        elif bank[i] < 0:
            withdrawal.append(bank[i])

    print (sum(deposit, withdrawal))

statement([30.95, -15.67, 45.56, -55.00, 43.78])
```

The problem is that I can't add the float from a list. How can i do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I think they were looking for based on the problem description

```
def statement(bank):
    deposit = 0
    withdrawal = 0
    for transaction in bank:
        if transaction > 0:
            deposit += transaction
        else:
            withdrawal += transaction
    return [deposit, withdrawal]
```

The list should have two elements. The first is the sum of all deposits, the second is the sum of all withdrawals.

```
>>> statement([30.95, -15.67, 45.56, -55.00, 43.78])
[120.29, -70.67]
```